# How to allocate memory dynamically for class using new in C++?

Tags: c++, linux

have a following class:

```
class mem
{
  private:
        int data;
  public:
        mem(){}
        mem(int a)
        {
                data=a;
        }
        void dataDis()
        {
                cout <<"valu of i is "<< data << endl;
        }

};
```

How to allocate memory for 10 object of this class by using parametrized constructor and new operator?

Comment: Do you want 10 objects all in one array, or do you want 10 pointers to independently allocated objects?

Comment: Do you want them all initialised with the same value, or with 10 different values? Do you specifically need to use `new` or would the more convenient `std::array` or `std::vector` be acceptable?

Comment: @Adrian I want both array of 10 object as well as 10 pointer independently allocated.

Comment: @Mike No i need to allocate only using new operator and should be initialized with different value

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you need to use `new` directly, then you can do it easily for ten separate objects:

```
mem * mem1 = new mem(42);
// and so on
```

You can't specify initialisers when allocating an array with `new`; you'll have to let them be default-initialised, then reassign them:

```
mem * mems = new mem[10];
mems[0] = mem(42);
// and so on
```

Don't forget to assign them to smart pointers (or delete them when you've finished with them, if the weird requirement to use `new` also forbids other forms of sensible memory management).

When you find yourself working under less insane restrictions, use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of mucking around with raw memory allocations:

```
std::vector<mem> mems = {42, 63, /* and so on */};
```

Comment: The syntax for initializing a vector requires the new initializer list feature in C++11 - not available in all compilers yet.